# Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be positive real numbers. Prove the following inequality.

Tags: inequality, real-numbers

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ be positive real numbers. Prove the following inequality;
$$
(a+b+c)\Bigl(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\Bigr)
\ge 9+3\sqrt[\scriptstyle 3]{\cfrac{(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2}{a^2b^2c^2}}
$$

*The root is a cube root in case it isn't clear.*

I'm trying to use the AM-GM, Cauchy-Schwarz, triangle and other inequalities.

Comment: Various solutions on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1446384p8265190, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1445858p8257615, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1090113p4842594

Answer (score 5):

Using the AM-GM inequality, we have
$$(a+b+c) \cdot \Bigl(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\Bigr) - 9  = \left(\frac{a}{b}+ \frac{b}{a}-2\right)+\left(\frac{b}{c}+ \frac{c}{b}-2\right)+\left(\frac{c}{a}+ \frac{a}{c}-2\right)$$
$$= \frac{(a-b)^2}{ab}+\frac{(b-c)^2}{bc}+\frac{(c-a)^2}{ac}\geqslant 3\sqrt[\scriptstyle 3]{\cfrac{(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2}{a^2b^2c^2}}.$$

Comment: +1 you may want to add that you used the langranges identity..